# Three.js wireframehelper inside group bad positioning

Tags: three.js

I have a group object, inside it I have a PlaneBufferGeometry and a wireframehelper, both added to the group. The planebufferGeometry is created at 0,0,0.

I use:

```
group.setposition(100,100,0)
```

And I see the planebuffer is placed at 100,100,0.

But the wireframehelper is placed at 200,200,0?
(it uses the position data twice? )

If I place another object inside the group all is OK, but the wireframehelper is always placed wrong. Am I missing something?

Comment: The `WireframeHelper` gets its data from the object it is assigned to so depending on when you create it and when you render it I can see that behavior as possible.

Comment: @gaitac I think ths is a bug  as you can see at jsfillde, the first group is well done, the second shows the error. The wireframehelper does not work fine http://jsfiddle.net/9g9wb2o5/1/ . I'm going to wait for any opinion before create a bug report on github

Comment: To use fromBufferGeometry() does the same ...

Comment: `WireframeHelper` must be a child of the scene.

Comment: @westLangley Why must be a child ? I want to create multiple elements inside a group. As I can't have a wireframe representation of buffergeometry I use the wireframeheper but In case I want to hide or change some element I have to make the things twice. Is there any way to fix this behaviour ?  As stob said, the starting point is shifted from the center of the group. Why ? I'm using the wifreframehelper to show the edges of some member of the group, not the group.  Any way to fix this ? The grouping approach would not have to broke the wireframe-object link... What do you think

Comment: `WireframeHelper` must be a child of the scene. Study the source code.

Comment: @WestLangley. Sorry, I don't see the place at code where it's said that wireframe must be a child of the scene. The wireframe is a new line object and IMHO I think it should behave as a normal object inside a group.

Comment: I posted an answer to address your questions in the comments. Sorry I didn't do that in the first place. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WireframeHelper` must be a child of the scene.

This is a consequence of how the code was written. Consider it a feature.

The code that is forcing this issue is in the `THREE.WireframeHelper`constructor:

```
this.matrix = object.matrixWorld;
this.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
```

The benefit is if you transform your object, or your object's parent, the wireframe will transform also.

The side effect is the wireframe helper must be a child of the scene directly.

three.js r.71

Comment: Sorry for forget to accept. However, I keep thinking that it should have a way to have a wireframe object inside an object with a right and expected behaviour.  In addition, setting the linked object visble property does not hide the wireframehelper. Could be possible to have some fix for this ? I imagine a lot of objects with children elements that need to be showed with a wireframe object.   So... we have also the problem of wireframe material does not work fine with buffergeometry, so we have to use the wireframe object, but this object is 'free' ....Hope understand my post

Comment: `WireframeHelper` should work correctly with `BufferGeometry` in r.72, but yes, it does not handle children.

Answer (score 0):

1) There is no need to place the wireframehelper in the group. Just add it to the scene. http://jsfiddle.net/9g9wb2o5/2/

```
scene.add(new THREE.WireframeHelper( mesh ));
```

2) When you put the wireframehelper in the group, the starting point for its construction is shifted from the center of the group to the world coordinates of the object to which you want the wireframehelper . Maybe it is a bug, well, or a game of relativity.

Comment: The grouping approach can't be broke the wireframe-object link...  The wireframehelper must show the object which it is linked...